# Mockery forgetting byDefault setup when using shouldReceive for the same method but different arguments

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, tdd, mockery

We are experimenting a strange behaviour of *Mockery* (0.9.2) while tdd-ing a *Symfony* controller which makes use of several request parameters grabbed using the *Request* service. We are using *PHPUnit* (3.7) as testing framework.

The way we approach TDD is using *setUp* method for creating mocks and configuring them by using *byDefault()* so they can provide a neutral happy-flow scenario. Then, in each test method, we become specific about our expectations about mock behaviour.

I isolated the problem in a proof of concept test just for making the analysis easier. Here we go.

This is the test class itself:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $request;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->request = \Mockery::mock('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request');

        $this->request->shouldReceive('get')->with('a')->andReturnNull()->byDefault();
        $this->request->shouldReceive('get')->with('b')->andReturnNull()->byDefault();
    }

    public function test_bar_checks_request_a_parameter()
    {
        $this->request->shouldReceive('get')->with('a')->andReturn('a')->once();

        $foo = new Foo($this->request);
        $foo->bar();
    }
}
```

And this is the tested class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Foo
{
    private $request;

    function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        $a = $this->request->get('a');
        $b = $this->request->get('b');
    }
}
```

In the test *test_bar_checks_request_a_parameter* I would expect *bar()* method to get 'a' when calling *get('a')* on the request mock while getting *null* when calling *get('b')* instead.

But, instead, we are getting this error:

```
No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Symfony_Component_HttpFoundation_Request::get("b").
```

Which seems to say that the *Request* mock forgot the setUp we made for *get('b')* call

```
shouldReceive('get')->with('b')->andReturnNull()->byDefault()
```

Is this a Mockery limitation? Is a bad approach on our side, a test smell maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Mockery limitation. When you set a new expectation for a method, Mockery disables all the `byDefault()` expectations for that method, even if they were set with distinct arguments.

There is an open issue regarding that:

https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/353

You can solve this by using an array of values and a function that will compute the return value each time. The trick is making the array accesible from the test methods so you can change the return values:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  private $request;

  private $get_return_values = array();

  public function setUp()
  {
      $this->request = \Mockery::mock('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request');
      $this->request->shouldReceive('get')->andReturnUsing(function($arg) {
         return isset($this->get_return_values[$arg]) ? $this->get_return_values[$arg] : null;
      });
  }

  public function test_bar_checks_request_a_parameter()
  {
      $this->get_return_values['a'] = 'a';

      $foo = new Foo($this->request);
      $foo->bar();
  }
}
```